# retrieving Artifacts version from artifactory into Jenkins choice param

Tags: jenkins, groovy, artifactory, jenkins-groovy

I wrote an API call to artifactory which retrieves artifacts versions,
Now I want to try and make Jenkins load the options from the array the api makes every time someone tries to run the pipeline.

for example, I just released a new version to artifactory and I want people who run the pipeline to automatically see the option in the choice parameter without actually changing the Jenkins file and adding the option.

I understood it is possible via the active choice plugin but can't find any example for it any advice?

I expect Jenkins to update the choice param with live data from the API calls